# why align 8 for int?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When i compile c++ class to IR code, the int assignment statement will turn into `align 8`(while one member is double). Why? When all members are int type, it will be `align 4`.

```cpp
class _AA_ {
  public:
  int    a  = 11;
  double b  = 22;
};
```

This will turn into:

```
define linkonce_odr void @_ZN4_AA_C2Ev(%class._AA_*) unnamed_addr #1 align 2 {
  %2 = alloca %class._AA_*, align 8
  store %class._AA_* %0, %class._AA_** %2, align 8
  %3 = load %class._AA_*, %class._AA_** %2, align 8
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds %class._AA_, %class._AA_* %3, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 11, i32* %4, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds %class._AA_, %class._AA_* %3, i32 0, i32 1
  store double 2.200000e+01, double* %5, align 8
  ret void
}
```

Comment: In your snippet you are working with pointers only. They are aligned to 8 bytes, because you are compiling for 64-bit target, I suspect.

Comment: @arrowd, it's alignment of the target, not the pointer. It is because the first (but not necessarily any other) element is known to be aligned the same as the containing object. Note that it clearly states the alignment will be 4 when there is no `double` in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are wrapping the two variables in a structure (class and struct are the same for this purpose), their relative positions must always be the same. So the structure as a whole must have highest alignment of all members, which is 8 from the double.

And since you have standard layout object, the first declared member must be at offset 0, so also has the alignment of the containing object.

If you only have integers, their alignment is just 4, so the object has only 4 as well.

Other than the first member will only get their natural alignment generally as they will be placed after the preceding element with just enough padding to satisfy that. It is only the first element that inherits the alignment of the containing object.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it seems not always in this way, please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @vifird, I said the *first* member has alignment of the object. If there is room at offset +4 for a second int, that one will only have it's natural alignment of 4.